# mac: compare two folders, extract non-identical photos only

Tags: macos, directory

I have been looking in S.O. for ways to compare two folders to extract only the "new" or the "non-identical" photos. I have two large folders and I only want the new files, I need to identify them. Is there a way to do it? or an application to do it?

situation: with the iOS8, I gave it a try, and then I revert back to iOS711. but my most recent backup (the one I did before upgrading to iOS8) was corrupt, due to the downgrade I did. 
Now, I have a copy of my iOS photos from the recent backup (I had to use backup extractor to extract the photos from), but I also have the photos from a month old backup that I restored into my phone after I gave up on the corrupt and recent backup.

I have now two sets of photo libraries. one with the up to date photos (which cannot be restored in the iPhone through iTunes), and one with the month old photo library (which was restored to my iPhone through iTunes easily).

I extracted photos from both backups, and I ended up with two directories. I only need the new photos (the difference between the two folders).

I hope it's now clearer, and more detailed.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `NSFileManager` has methods that return the list of items in a directory if that's what you want to compare.  Maybe you should define what you mean by "non-identical" though.

Comment: @PhillipMills thanks for the comment. I have two folders, one has items: 1,2,3,4,5 and the other folder has items: 1,2,4
I need to compare both folders, and extract the items that doesn't have an identical peer in the other folder. So, the results should be: 3 & 5. 

Hopefully I have explained it alright?

Answer (score 0):

Can you install `duff` via homebrew or macports? If so, the following should give you a list of files that occur only once:

```
$ duff -r -f '' folder1 folder2 | sort > duplicate_files.txt
$ find folder1 folder2 -print | sort > all_files.txt
$ diff all_files.txt duplicate_files.txt | grep '^< ' | cut -c 3-
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install additional packages, this would also work:

```
sort <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2) | uniq -u
```

That'll sort the list of files in both directories and then return only the items that appear only once. If you want to also return the locations of those files, you could then search for them.

This compares files by name, which might not be desirable. If you want to compare them by something else (e.g. size), then the answer gets a little more complicated.